# Get name and id of autocomplete suggestions into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-typeahead

I have the code below, which I use to type and suggest a few relation names in an input field. The data variable right now returns only names like:

```
var data = ["name": "Relation 1", "name":"Relation 2"]
```

I modified it and now it has data like:

```
   var data = [
        {"id":1,"name":"Foo"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Bar"},
        {"id":3,"name":"Foo Bar"}
    ];
```

How do I append the id of the selected name in the `id` input?

```
$('input.relation').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get('live_search.php?filter=relation', { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
        });
    }
});


 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="relation"> Relation </label>
                <input class="relation form-control" type="text">
                <input class="relation-id form-control" type="text" name="id">
 </div>
```

Comment: ["name": "Relation 1" :"id":"1", "name":"Relation 2":"id":"2"]  this is not a valid JS syntax, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Praveen Sorry, my mistake. I edited it. What i want to do is not only to get the name of the relation but also it's id. because I need it to store it in the database.

Comment: @Praveen something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/G3BPv/

Comment: @DaniM I don't understand what you wan't exactly, but given your fiddle above I edited it so you can get also the ID's from request: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3BPv/58/)

Comment: @Gabriel thank you. I have made it work like that, but I'd want my source to be coming from this php file, like in my example. Because like that I don't have to pre-load all, but I query in the run..